# possible bug with mysql variables in birt/pentaho report

Tags: mysql, variables, pentaho, birt

strange error with birt and pentaho 3.9.
i got the following query :

```
SELECT 
@med:=care_med_products_main_movements.medicament, 
@prc:=care_med_products_main_movements.price,
@exp_date:=care_med_products_main_movements.expiry_date, 
@pharma:=care_department.nr,
...
```

under Pentao @exp_date works with a data type of Blob,and under Birt it works with a data type of Date.
my installation is pentaho 3.9 ce, and birt web viewer 3.7.2 installed under pentaho.
the have the same jdbc drivers, and everything birt related is identical.

regards
gj.

Comment: Hmm, you should file a JIRA ticket at http://jira.pentaho.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-7211